# Why and when should I use command bus vs controller laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

New command bus feature inclusion in laravel 5 is getting me confused.
Why and when should I use commands while we can achieve same task in controller itself ?

**Command**

```
class PurchasePodcast extends Command implements SelfHandling {

protected $user, $podcast;

   /**
   * Create a new command instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function __construct(User $user, Podcast $podcast)
   {
       $this->user = $user;
       $this->podcast = $podcast;
   }

  /**
    * Execute the command.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {
       // Handle the logic to purchase the podcast...

        event(new PodcastWasPurchased($this->user, $this->podcast));
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use PurchasePodcast;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

   use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

   public function purchasePodcast($podcastId)
   {
      $this->dispatch(
         new PurchasePodcast(Auth::user(), Podcast::findOrFail($podcastId))
      );
  }
}
```

Why should I make it complex, while I can straight away do it in controller rather than using command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea comes from "Command Pattern" in which an object is used to encapsulate the information to perform an action.

Using Command pattern could make it easier to organize actions to perform in a software. The command, as an object, is reusable in more than one controller, thus let you DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Command object is also easier to test, because it is decoupled from controller.

Of course there is tradeoff in programming. You will have more classes (and files) when you use command pattern. So, use it when you need it. When you find a complex action to perform, and your controller starts getting fat, maybe you would want to take a look at this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use commands. It all depends on the size of your project. If you can get away with putting stuff in your controller, do it. There is no law here, only good/bad practices. And what is considered good practice isn't always the best option for what you are building.

As you said, why make it complex? Don't.